# sqlite3 unable to open any database in android lollipop physical device

Tags: android, sqlite, terminal-emulator

I have a sample database file in my phone and would like to manage it using 
Please bear in mind that this is an error from a physical android device and not on an android emulator.

terminal emulator:

```
su
#
sqlite3 -version
3.7.6.3-Titanium (I copied sqlite3 from an app called Titanium Buckup 
                  as suggested from my google search result).
sqlite3 mydb
sqlite version 3.7.6.3-Titanium
Enter ".help" for instructions
sqlite3 mydb "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE info = x";
Error: unable to open database "mydb": unable to open database file.
```

Issue fixed: See post below.

Comment: Is the path to mydb correct?

Comment: Yes, I think it's on the right path cause the dialogue, "enter sqlite command separated by ";" appears each time I enter sqlite3 mydb.

Comment: Error fixed: The problem is with my messed-up system partition. I recently installed CM21.1 ROM known to have emulated storage bugs.
To fix the problem, I mounted the system as r/w with an app named  [Super Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=gpc.myweb.hinet.net.TaskManager).